# Which tools can I use to analyze memory dumps in macOS?

Tags: macos, memory

I am trying to analyze memory dumps from specific processes on the MacOS. I am using commands:

```
lldb --attach-pid 1041
process save-core "core"
```

And the size of the file `core` is 3.3GB. With the same application process on Windows I've go 150 MB and on linux 600 MB. Makes it hard to analyze it at that size.

What are reliable tools for the analyzing mem-dumps on MacOS, regarding looking for the sensitive data?

Comment: You had two questions in there, I edited it down to one ("Why" questions don't work so well, also it seems to be a side issue). What have you already done in terms of research regarding tools? What do you use on Linux?

Comment: I used `xxd` and `grep` on MacOS. However I am thinking if there is any way to improve performance of searching in so big binary files. I used also Xcode and it has problem with searching exact number of results of specific string

Comment: How does size limit your analysis? Are you scrolling through it page by page in an editor? Since you already have a good answer, maybe a follow on question if you want to tick this one as answered might work best if you still need help.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the memory dump being so big is that the application has mapped that much memory. It might not actually be "using" it, but it could mapped in the way of memory mapped files, or just "blank" (unused) space.

In terms of tools for analysing memory dumps, it depends entirely on what you're looking for and whether or not you know the internal data structures of the application you're analysing.

If this is a third party application, you do not have the source code for, and you're looking for sensitive data in the form of text - I would run the memory dump through the `strings` program:

```
strings core
```

An idea could be to save this intermediate result, and use that for later searching:

```
strings core > text
grep searchstring text
```

If you want to have a tool that actually understands the contents of the memory dump (for example to differentiate between different types of memory mappings), you can use [Rekall](http://www.rekall-forensic.com). Note that it is unfortunately no longer maintained for macOS.

Comment: That's works better thanks. The other tool which works considerably good, with GUI by the way, is Synalyze IT! It is not a third party application but mine and I am looking for weaknesses in it. I am understanding now mechanism of memory mapping and I see a lot of blank space in the HEX. Do you know maybe any possible fix for compiling it, in order to reduce the size of used memory?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use the term "compile" here, but yes, you can dump the core without the memory mapped regions in order to save space on disk.

Comment: Ok, so how to turn of dumping mapped memory and save only private memory?

Comment: Mapped memory is also private. Can you share what exactly you're trying to achieve here? - You're currently using core dumps - they're intended to contain the entire mapped address space, otherwise they won't "work" (i.e. you cannot restore the process state into the debugger afterwards). It seems like you do not really want a core dump, but you should rather just dump the memory regions you're interested in into a file, and search through that.

Comment: You have mentioned using Linux - in that case, you are already not dumping memory mapped files, as that is by default filtered away. You can use the /proc/<pid>/coredump_filter functionality to select what to dump (setting bit 2 and 3 will give you dumps of mapped files as well).

Comment: In lldb, you can use the "memory dump" command to dump specific parts of memory. If you do not know your memory mappings, I would suggest using a tool to handle that for you.

Comment: I used "vmap" to get virtual memory map on MacOS and I am able to see which memory regions are dedicated only for my application. I'll try then to dump it by "lldb". However on Linux I used "gcore" and I exclude uninterested regions by the command line option and I am wonder if it is possible on MacOS

Comment: As I wrote before, the coredump_filter option you have been using with gcore is Linux specific, and is not available on macOS. You do not want a core dump. Instead you should use the "memory dump" command in lldb.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got something that I want. The minor problem still is the performance of lldb dumping memory. On linux I used dd command but I believed that will be difficult workaround on macOS concerning lack of /proc/ catalog

Comment: What kind of performance are you seing using the memory dump command in lldb?

Comment: I mean the time of the perform dump and for the 20 Mb dump is around one minute( using lldb (so it's significant if I want to test it while developing) and on linux with dd its 10-15 times faster.

Comment: That sounds terribly slow - so you're saying it takes 1 minute to dump 20 megabyte of RAM?

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent utility (although retired it still works):
https://github.com/google/rekall/tree/master/tools/osx/MacPmem

> MacPmem enables read/write access to physical memory. It simultaneously exposes a wealth of useful information about the operating system and hardware it's running on through an informational device and sysctl interface.

It exposes two devices:

/dev/pmem # Physical memory read access (can be built with write support).

/dev/pmem_info # Informational dump.

Comment: Can you expand a bit with an [edit]?  Link only answers tend to be removed.